# Rails: getting nil values in hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm getting nil values when I'm using hidden field

```
<%= form_for @hour do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Sunday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Monday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Tuesday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Wednesday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Thursday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Friday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[]", :value => "Saturday" %>
<% end %>
```

My parameters:

```
"days"=>[nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]
```

Am I doing hidden fields wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try losing the symbol. ie remove ":value =>"

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: @FrederickCheung an example of sunday's html: `<input id="hour_days[]" name="hour[days[]]" type="hidden" value="Sunday">` This looks the same to all the other ones except the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the below code helps.

```
<%= form_for @hour do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[0]", :value => "Sunday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[1]", :value => "Monday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[2]", :value => "Tuesday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[3]", :value => "Wednesday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[4]", :value => "Thursday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[5]", :value => "Friday" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "days[6]", :value => "Saturday" %>
<% end %>
```

Params:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√",authenticity_token"=>"m84ly0Ok8NWKzqv2ZGZvtP1tRoSZ3M0OlL7W5W5Pk+I=", 
"hour"=>{"days"=>{"0"=>"Sunday", "1"=>"Monday", "2"=>"Tuesday",
 "3"=>"Wednesday", "4"=>"Thursday", "5"=>"Friday", "6"=>"Saturday"}},
"commit"=>"Create hour "}
```

**UPDATED** 
Dynamic :

```
<%= form_for @hour do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Sunday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Monday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Tuesday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Wednesday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Thursday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Friday" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field "days][", :value => "Saturday" %>
<% end %>
```

output:

```
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√",  "authenticity_token"=>"jxCDmSoKjclXu4ySSWp/gW19Ejy4tY3NwdBW/l/+lRU=", "user"=>{"hour"=>["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]}, "commit"=>"Create Hour"}
```

Comment: Eventually I would need to dynamically add more days in the week. Sometimes it will be duplicate days, so I can't hardcode the numbers because there maybe multiple Sundays or Wednesdays, etc...

Comment: am not sure how your view file is but there has to be some thing based on which you will want to have total number of dynamic fields..

Comment: Updated my answer.. now it sends the params. Remember to reverse the brackets

Comment: This reverse brackets ][ works because it generates input field name property in correct way example: <input id="hour_days][" type="hidden" value="Tuesday" name="hour[days][]">.  but when i use brackets in normal way the name property has values like this -> name="user[days[]]"

Comment: the reverse bracket works. Is there a reason why it does this? I thought it would need to be `days[]`. Ive never done it reverse before.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use hidden fields in the view to get an array of day names in the params?

You could do this in the controller instead:

```
params.merge!('days' => Date::DAYNAMES)
```

which will give you in the params:

```
"days"=>["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Or, if you need the array of days inside the `hour` hash:

```
params['hour'].merge!('days' => Date::DAYNAMES)
```

Or, if you need the day names to be localised, instead of `Date::DAYNAMES` use:

```
I18n.t(:'date.day_names')
```

Comment: I'm doing hidden because I like to dynamically add more days if I need to